# Can't access function in namespace

Tags: c++, function, class, namespaces

I just created some sort of library to automate some C++ stuff, problem is, one file contains a namespace with a function, while the other contains a class that tries to call that function.

The compiler says the function is not defined.

**File1.cpp**

```
namespace cs{
    void func(){
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

**File2.cpp**

```
class cx{
    private:
    void custom(){
        cs::func(); //Compiler says "cs" has not been declared.
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you even read the info for your `compiler-construction` tag?

Comment: How is `cs::func` name being declared in `File2.cpp` (are you forgetting to declare it at all)? Is the namespace actually at all relevant, or do you get the same behavior with it removed?

Comment: Did you `#include "test1.cpp”` at the top of file2.cpp

Comment: @aProfessionalHelpNeeder yes I did.

Comment: @aProfessionalHelpNeeder do not `#include` cpp files. Make a header file that declares the function, and have both cpp files `#include` that header instead

Comment: This is an obvious typo: with the actual code, exactly as shown, the declaration of the function is missing from "File2.cpp".

Comment: @aProfessionalHelpNeeder functions inside namespaces can be called if they're called inside a class.

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: you say "The compiler says the function is not defined." and then in a comment "//Compiler says "cs" has not been declared.". Is it not defined or not declared? What does the compiler error say really?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah you're right but he doesn't have a .hpp file as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a declaration of `cs::func()` inside of `File2.cpp`, eg:

File2.cpp

```
namespace cs{
    void func();
}

class cx{
    private:
    void custom(){
        cs::func();
    }
}
```

This will allow the compiler to know about the function's existence in `File2.cpp`, and as long as you compile and link both `.cpp` files, the linker will be able to find the function.

That said, it would be better to move that function declaration into a `.h` file instead, which you can then `#include` where needed, eg:

File1.h

```
namespace cs{
    void func();
}
```

File1.cpp

```
#include "File1.h"

namespace cs{
    void func(){
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

File2.cpp

```
#include "File1.h"

class cx{
    private:
    void custom(){
        cs::func();
    }
}
```